# How do I use shared configurations across SBT (Play) multi-projects?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I have several SBT 0.13 / Play 2.2 projects (websites). They are all multi-module as they share some common functionality. This makes their project configuration files both complex and almost identical, but not quite.

I would like to be able to share as much as possible of these configuration files across the projects (frequent play updates makes keeping 5+ websites up to date a royal pain, not to mention all the almost-identical-but-evolving dependency lists across the projects).

build.properties and plugins.sbt are identical across projects and can be overwritten by a simple script. Great.

Build.scala is trickier - I would like to introduce a shared base class like so:

```
abstract class MyBuildBase extends Build { ... }
```

that in Build.scala do:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends MyBuildBuild { ... }
```

In order for this to make any sense at all, MyBuildBase.scala needs to be shared across projects. This can be done with svn:external, which operates on directories. Which means I need to somehow make this shared directory accessible when Build.scala is compiled (otherwise sbt complains loudly).

Reading http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html and http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html it seems like this should be possible.

However, it is exceptionally unclear to me what to actually put in the project/project/Build.scala file to actually achieve this - I can't find an example of **"an sbt build file that's intended to build an sbt build file and include some extra source files in the build"**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you probably want to do is create a plugin, or shared library.

You can make an sbt project with a build like follows:

`build.sbt`

```
sbtPlugin := true

organization := "you"

name := "common-build"

version := "1.0"
```

Then create in `src/main/scala` your abstract class "MyBuildBase".   Release this project as an sbt plugin.

Then in your other projects, you can use this as a library/plugin.  In `project/plugins.sbt` add:

```
addSbtPlugin("you" % "common-build" % "1.0")
```

And this will resolve your common build library *when building your build*.

If you need more information, look up more about sbt plugins and ignore the part about making something that extends a Plugin.  Plugins are just libraries versioned with sbt's version number and your own.   You should be able to put whatever code you want in there to share between builds.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Turns out SVN can handle external files and not just directories since v1.6, so I solved it that way instead as it was easier in my particular case. However, your answer covers the question I actually asked, so marking it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Note: in 2016, `Build.scala` is deprecated for `Build.sbt`.

Here is the new (Dec. 2016) [multi-module with App Scala sbt template](https://github.com/lewismj/sbt-template.g8) by [Michael Lewis](https://github.com/lewismj).

> Usage

```
sbt new lewismj/sbt-template.g8
```

> You can then run:

```
sbt compile
sbt publish-local
sbt assembly
```

It is based on [Scala SBT template (Library)](https://github.com/lewismj/sbt-library-template.g8)

> This giter8 template will write SBT build files for a Scala library.